# Different ZonedDateTime of GMT and BST become same Instant after toInstant conversion in Scala

Tags: scala, java-time, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter, java.time.instant

to summarize my question, I have 2 different ZonedDateTime objects with GMT and BST but same local time. They become the same Instant values after toInstant conversion. I am expecting after conversion, they should be different values because although they are both 'Tue Feb 23 18:00:46 2021', the strings are representing time for different time zones. I am not sure whether this is a bug of library itself or I am doing something wrong.

I have 2 different ZonedDateTime generated from this piece of Scala code:

```
import ...
import java.util.{Set => JavaSet}
val string2 = "Tue Feb 23 18:00:46 BST 2021" 
val string1 = "Tue Feb 23 18:00:46 GMT 2021" 
val timestampFormat: DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM ppd HH:mm:ss ")
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, JavaSet.of(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
    .appendPattern(" yyyy")
    .toFormatter(Locale.US)

val parsedZdt2: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(string2, timestampFormat)
val parsedZdt1: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(string1, timestampFormat)
println(parsedZdt1 == parsedZdt2)
println("parsedZdt1.toString: " + parsedZdt1.toString)
println("parsedZdt2.toString: " + parsedZdt2.toString)
```

This prints out:

```
false
parsedZdt1.toString: 2021-02-23T18:00:46Z[GMT]
parsedZdt2.toString: 2021-02-23T18:00:46Z[Europe/London]
```

However when I convert them to instant:

```
println(parsedZdt1.toInstant == parsedZdt2.toInstant)
println("parsedZdt1.toInstant.toString: " + parsedZdt1.toInstant.toString)
println("parsedZdt2.toInstant.toString: " + parsedZdt2.toInstant.toString)
```

I got this printed out:

```
true
parsedZdt1.toInstant.toString: 2021-02-23T18:00:46Z
parsedZdt2.toInstant.toString: 2021-02-23T18:00:46Z
```

My questions are

1. Why do the 2 values become the same after toInstant conversion?
2. Are the 2 values representing same time even before toInstant, i.e. , are parsedZdt1 and parsedZdt2 representing the same moment?

Thank you!

Comment: BST -- British Summer TIme -- does not exist in February. In February London and the UK are on GMT.

Comment: Where have you got those strings from? Could it be that by BST they intended one of Brazil/ian Summer Time, Bangladesh Standard Time, Bougainville Standard Time? All of these are taken from [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/). BTW a nice illustration why you should never use time zone abbreviations for transferring time zone information. They are so often ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks Ole! I was using an arbitrary string as input and I was not aware that BST and GMT can be the same sometimes as Basil and Alin pointed out in the answers. The problem I was trying to resolve was to interpret BST as British Summer Time rather than Bougainville Standard Time. I saw a similar question and was testing this appendZoneText method you put forward in that question. I agree zone name abbreviation should not be used. In my case, this is from upstream systems so unfortunately, I cannot use ZoneId in the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

You said:

> the strings are representing time for different time zones

Different time zones, yes, but the time zones happen to **share the same offset on that particular date**. Many time zones share the same offset, coincidentally, on particular dates.

London time is GMT/UTC time, sometimes, when not observing [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

## BST = GMT (sometimes)

If by `BST`, you mean the time zone `Europe/London`, that zone had an **offset of zero hours** from UTC/GMT on that date of 2021-02-23.

So 6 PM on February 23rd in London time was also 6 PM in GMT.

Later in the year, from March 28, 2021 to October 31, 2021, the UK observes DST. During those months their offset is **one hour *ahead* of UTC**.

See [*Time Change 2021 in England, United Kingdom*](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/england?year=2021) on TimeAndDate.com.

### Example code

Let’s compare two moments using `Instant#equals`.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 18 , 0 , 0 ) ;
boolean sameMoment = 
    ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ).toInstant()
    .equals(
        OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant()
    ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/DaEtBX).

> true

Change the month to June, during Daylight Saving Time observance.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JUNE , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 18 , 0 , 0 ) ;
boolean sameMoment = 
    ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ).toInstant()
    .equals(
        OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant()
    ) ;
```

> false

### `ZoneOffset`

Also, you can directly interrogate for the offset of a moment, in both `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` objects. Call `getOffset` to get a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 18 , 0 , 0 );

ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) );
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC );

ZoneOffset offsetLondon = zdtLondon.getOffset();
ZoneOffset offsetUtc = odtUtc.getOffset();

System.out.println( zdtLondon + " has an offset of: " + offsetLondon );
System.out.println( odtUtc + " has an offset of: " + offsetUtc );
```

We see both have an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, indicated by a `Z`, pronounced “Zulu”.

> 2021-02-23T18:00Z[Europe/London] has an offset of: Z
>
> 2021-02-23T18:00Z has an offset of: Z

Change the month to June, and we get different offsets. London time shows an hour ahead of UTC.

> 2021-06-23T18:00+01:00[Europe/London] has an offset of: +01:00
>
> 2021-06-23T18:00Z has an offset of: Z

Answer (score 1):

BST begins at 01:00 GMT every year on the last Sunday of March and ends at 01:00 GMT (02:00 BST) on the last Sunday of October.

In your example - 23rd of Feb represent the same time line even before the conversion. For the 2021 year, to see the 1 hour gap difference, you have to use a date between 28 March - 31 October inclusive, but with the appropriate hour.

E.g.:

```
  val string2 = "Tue Mar 30 18:00:46 BST 2021"
  val string1 = "Tue Mar 30 18:00:46 GMT 2021"
```

yields:

```
parsedZdt1.toString: 2021-03-30T18:00:46Z[GMT]
parsedZdt2.toString: 2021-03-30T18:00:46+01:00[Europe/London]
```